# InnerText XmlNode C#

Tags: c#, xml, innertext, innerxml

I am trying to create an XMLDocument in C#. This is the file that I am trying to parse.

```
<root>
 <child/>
 some text here
</root>
```

However, when I try to assign the "some text here" to the  element, I run into a problem.
In the beginning I have the XmlNode's

```
InnerText=""
```

and the XmlNode's

```
InnerXml=</child>
```

By doing

```
node.InnerText+="some text here";
```

my

```
InnerXml="";
```

I do not understand what am I doing wrong.

**Note** 
If I have the following XML - where the text comes before the child, I have no issues.

```
<root>
 some text here
 <child/>
</root>
```

Comment: The file itself is wrong. The last element should be `</root>`, to close it, not `<root>` (new "root" node opening). And you either have `<child/>` (immediately closed) or `<child>` later followed by `</child>`. `</child/>` is not proper XML.

Comment: Check my documentation abbout XmlDocument class this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1528/xmldocument-and-the-system-xml-namespace#t=201704030752424634413

Comment: Sorry, that was my spelling. Fixed it now.

Comment: @TimonPost you are using the .SelectSingleNode(node_path) but I do not have the node_path since I am using large xml files. The above XML is just a very simple one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to manipulate the XML by changing the `InnerXxx` properties, you should do it by invoking [`AppendChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx).

You'd want to append an [`XmlText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltext(v=vs.110).aspx) element as a new child.